# Setup a clearkey server for shaka player didn't work?

Tags: drm, mpeg-dash

I've created a test html page for playing a MPEG-CENC protected MPEG-DASH video, and I can play if I specify kid: key pair in player.configure().

Then I want to setup a clearkey server. Refer to [DRM Configuration](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-drm-config.html) section of Shaka Player documents, I changed the code to specify the url to get the license like below. But the page never get touched when I set a breakpoint in Page_Load event in Visual Studio. There is no error on console of browser.

The browser I use is Firefox 53.0.2 and Chrome 58.0.3029.96. Did I miss something?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/2.1.0/shaka-player.compiled.js"></script>
    <title>MPEG-DASH Player Test</title>
    <script>
        //MPEG-DASH stream encrypted with MPEG-CENC:
        var manifestUri = '/dashtest_encrypted/stream.mpd';

        function initApp() {
            // Install built-in polyfills to patch browser incompatibilities.
            shaka.polyfill.installAll();

            // Check to see if the browser supports the basic APIs Shaka needs.
            if (shaka.Player.isBrowserSupported()) {
                // Everything looks good!
                initPlayer();
            } else {
                // This browser does not have the minimum set of APIs we need.
                console.error('Browser not supported!');
            }
        }

        function initPlayer() {
            // Create a Player instance.
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var player = new shaka.Player(video);

            // Configue
            player.configure({
                drm: {
                    servers: {
                        'org.w3.clearkey': '/clearkey/GetLic.aspx'
                    },
                    clearKeys: {
                        //'kid': 'key'
                    }
                }
            });

            // Attach player to the window to make it easy to access in the JS console.
            window.player = player;

            // Listen for error events.
            player.addEventListener('error', onErrorEvent);

            // Try to load a manifest.
            // This is an asynchronous process.
            player.load(manifestUri).then(function () {
                // This runs if the asynchronous load is successful.
                console.log('The video has now been loaded!');
            }).catch(onError);  // onError is executed if the asynchronous load fails.
        }

        function onErrorEvent(event) {
            // Extract the shaka.util.Error object from the event.
            onError(event.detail);
        }

        function onError(error) {
            // Log the error.
            console.error('Error code', error.code, 'object', error);

            alert(error.code);
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initApp);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay controls></video>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the content of stream.MPD:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<MPD mediaPresentationDuration="PT12M3.022S" minBufferTime="PT15.48S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">
  <!-- Created with Bento4 mp4-dash.py, VERSION=1.7.0-614 -->
  <Period>
    <!-- Video -->
    <AdaptationSet maxHeight="720" maxWidth="1280" mimeType="video/mp4" minHeight="720" minWidth="1280" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
      <!-- MPEG Common Encryption -->
      <ContentProtection cenc:default_KID="7a4e12f1-8610-291f-386c-7ac1b9425abf" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
      <SegmentTemplate duration="15482" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" timescale="1000"/>
      <Representation bandwidth="1901600" codecs="avc1.64001F" frameRate="30000/1001" height="720" id="video/avc1" scanType="progressive" width="1280"/>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <!-- Audio -->
    <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
      <!-- MPEG Common Encryption -->
      <ContentProtection cenc:default_KID="7a4e12f1-8610-291f-386c-7ac1b9425abf" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
      <SegmentTemplate duration="15482" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" timescale="1000"/>
      <Representation audioSamplingRate="44100" bandwidth="200442" codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="audio/und/mp4a">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```

Comment: The Page_load event is an ASP concept so I'm not sure it would apply here - if you use the browser debugger you can get a breakpoint directly and see what is happening. Can you show the manifest file also - the playback problem may be there.

Comment: @Mick: I use ASP.net to implement the server side functionality. In this case, it's the license issuing. I've added the content of manifest file(stream.mpd) to the question.

Comment: The manifest looks ok - Shaka player should work though the key systems it knows as you have only specified CENC. I would really think that using the browser debugger tools to step through the code would be the next best step, and you can post what you find here if you don't see an obvious answer. BTW, the reason there are not many example using a clear key service from a license server is that it provides only minimal additional security for the effort.

Comment: My current problem is that the player doesn't even "ask" the url for license. The server side breakpoint is not hitted, no entry in http log, nothing. I use Shaka Player 2.1.0 on CDN, so is it a bug? Is there any working example about this?

Comment: https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com includes working widevine and playready examples.

Answer (score 5):

After a very long time testing and comparison, I noticed that my .mpd file didn't have **cenc:pssh** tag, which resulted this problem. I recreated the .mpd and Shaka Player FINALLY asked the server.

The corrected .mpd is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<MPD mediaPresentationDuration="PT12M3.022S" minBufferTime="PT15.48S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011" type="static" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013">
  <!-- Created with Bento4 mp4-dash.py, VERSION=1.7.0-614 -->
  <Period>
    <!-- Video -->
    <AdaptationSet maxHeight="720" maxWidth="1280" mimeType="video/mp4" minHeight="720" minWidth="1280" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
      <!-- EME Common Encryption -->
      <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:1077efec-c0b2-4d02-ace3-3c1e52e2fb4b" value="cenc">
        <cenc:pssh>AAAANHBzc2gBAAAAEHfv7MCyTQKs4zweUuL7SwAAAAF6ThLxhhApHzhsesG5Qlq/AAAAAA==</cenc:pssh>
      </ContentProtection>
      <!-- MPEG Common Encryption -->
      <ContentProtection cenc:default_KID="7a4e12f1-8610-291f-386c-7ac1b9425abf" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
      <SegmentTemplate duration="15482" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" timescale="1000"/>
      <Representation bandwidth="1901627" codecs="avc1.64001F" frameRate="30000/1001" height="720" id="video/avc1" scanType="progressive" width="1280"/>
    </AdaptationSet>
    <!-- Audio -->
    <AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" segmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1">
      <!-- EME Common Encryption -->
      <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:1077efec-c0b2-4d02-ace3-3c1e52e2fb4b" value="cenc">
        <cenc:pssh>AAAANHBzc2gBAAAAEHfv7MCyTQKs4zweUuL7SwAAAAF6ThLxhhApHzhsesG5Qlq/AAAAAA==</cenc:pssh>
      </ContentProtection>
      <!-- MPEG Common Encryption -->
      <ContentProtection cenc:default_KID="7a4e12f1-8610-291f-386c-7ac1b9425abf" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" value="cenc"/>
      <SegmentTemplate duration="15482" initialization="$RepresentationID$/init.mp4" media="$RepresentationID$/seg-$Number$.m4s" startNumber="1" timescale="1000"/>
      <Representation audioSamplingRate="44100" bandwidth="200442" codecs="mp4a.40.2" id="audio/und/mp4a">
        <AudioChannelConfiguration schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:23003:3:audio_channel_configuration:2011" value="2"/>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
  </Period>
</MPD>
```